# Solve triangle from angle, adjacent site and area

Tags: triangles

I feel like this should be possible, since I got the angle and the length of one side, the only thing that could vary would be the other adjacent site.

However, since I also know the area, it seems to me that only one length of the unknown adjacent site is possible.

Assuming this reasoning is not wrong, I seem unable to find the right formulas in order to solve this problem. Searches mostly turn up results for right triangles or a bit different problems.

If it should indeed be possible, it would be of immense help if someone could point me to which formulas I can combine to solve the triangle.

Comment: You know, $2 \times S = a \times b \times \sin C$?

Comment: @user202729 Indeed I did not, thank you. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [this (external) site](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-area-triangle-without-right-angle.html), the formula

$$ S = \frac 1 2 \times a \times b \times \sin C$$

is listed, for calculating the area $S$ from two sides and the angle between.

Using the formula, we can calculate the other adjacent side from the area, the given side length and the angle. The other details should be easy.

Comment: It also helped me to understand that the h in the perhaps more known S = 1/2 * a * h formula can be replaced by b * sin(angle), which results in the S = 1/2 * a * b formula for right triangles because of sin(90°) = 1, so I'm leaving this here as a comment in case anyone finds the question.